# URL Pattern not matched. Multiple fragments

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url that contains multiple url fragments seperated by slashes. for example:

```
http://example.com/media/2/2/bloesem-14087278823-ojpg
http://example.com/media/2/2/bloesem-14087278823-ojpg/250x250
```

And in the .htaccess i have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule "^media/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)(/.*)$" "laravel-index.php" [L]
```

The problem is that the upper URL does not work. i must include the trailing slash like so:

```
http://example.com/media/2/2/bloesem-14087278823-ojpg/
```

What can i change to the regex to match the upper url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a second rule to match the missing paths

```
RewriteRule "^media/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)$" "laravel-index.php" [L]
RewriteRule "^media/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$" "laravel-index.php" [L]
```

or use a `?` to set your last group as optional (matches 0 or 1 time)

```
RewriteRule "^media/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)?$" "laravel-index.php" [L]
```